# Login Discovery page-- Need to provide userId twice for login

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, authentication, loginflow

i have implemented login discovery page which will ask to enter ferdation id and once fedrationid enters it will redirect to perticular flow.

Question here is when i am entering the fedrationId and its redirecting to single sign on ...again i need to add fedid
i need to enter fedid twice i,is there any way where in start page the fedid which will i enter will automatically take in sso page

```
   private PageReference getSsoRedirect(String DeveloperName,User user, String startUrl, Map<String, String> requestAttributes) {
    // You can look up if the user should log in with SAML or an Auth Provider and return the URL to initialize SSO. For example:
    SamlSsoConfig SSO = [select Id from SamlSsoConfig where developerName=:developerName limit 1];
    String ssoUrl = Auth.AuthConfiguration.getSamlSsoUrl(requestAttributes.get('MyDomainURL'), startUrl, SSO.Id);
    System.debug('requestAttributes>>>>>'+requestAttributes);
    System.debug('SSO>>>>>'+SSO);
    System.debug('ssoUrl >>>>>'+ssoUrl );
    if(ssoUrl!=null || ssoUrl!='') {
        return new PageReference(ssoUrl);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]

[image]

once i entered username in first screen ,why there is need to enter it again in second screen (which is redirected SSO)

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the second login prompt, you should craft a URL (and return it as a PageReference) that will do IdP- or SP-initiated SSO. Constructing this URL depends on your identity provider, it is not Salesforce-specific. The bypass will only work if you have previously authenticated with this identity provider.

See my [previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263129/need-help-on-salesforce-login-discovery-using-my-domain) for more info.